# Exception Handling in Angular Chained Methods?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic4, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a simple question & I think that would be easy to answer for Angular Experts.

I have a method like below:

```
 private uploadPicture(imagePath: string, apiUrl: string): Observable<ApiResponse<string>> {

   return this.convertFileFromFilePathToBlob(imagePath).pipe(
      switchMap(item => this.convertBlobToFormData(item)),
      switchMap(formData => this.postImageToServer(formData, apiUrl)),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            return throwError(new AppError(error));
        } else {
            return throwError(new AppError(null, 'Error occured at convertFileFromFilePathToBlob.'));
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

I have chained 3 methods in one method:

1. `convertFileFromFilePathToBlob`
2. `convertBlobToFormData`
3. `postImageToServer`

All 3 methods can raise/emit error at any point of failure. My question is about how to do exception handling in such cases?

Is my current implementation, having only one `catchError` is fine? If fine, will it be executed if any of the chained methods raise an error?

or

Do I need to use multiple `catchError` operators after each method to catch its error? If yes, I don't know how can I do that?

Can someone please explain how should I handle error in such cases?

Comment: One `catchError` is fine and it will be executed when any of them raise an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have only one `catchError`, which should be enough. But make sure its at the end of all other operators. Because it catches error, replaces the stream, and hence allowing stream to continue. For example refer the below bubble diagram.

[image]

[RxJS documentation on catchError](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/function/index.html#static-function-catchError)

[Angular University post](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/)

---

In your case, I do not see a reason to use `catchError`, you can just use `Observable`'s error handling. `.subscribe` takes a second parameter as error handling function.

Comment: You mean to say, I am re-throwing the error from catch also, that's why you don't see it's significance...right? And even if I don't catch & throw an error here then also it will hit error method of subscribing handler (if an error occurs)?

Comment: @AnkushJain Yes. `catchError` is useful when you need to weed out unwanted error, and the stream to continue. If the aim is to stop it, then just use subscription's error handler.